# Error during update with pacman

Tags: arch-linux

running pacman -Syu today and this error occurred:

```
(627/627) checking package integrity                                                                                                           \[########################################################################################\] 100%

error: libspeechd: signature from "Alexander Epaneshnikov <[email@alex19ep.me](mailto:email@alex19ep.me)\>" is unknown trust

:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/libspeechd-0.11.1-2-x86\_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).

Do you want to delete it? \[Y/n\] n

error: mujs: signature from "Daniel Bermond <[dbermond@archlinux.org](mailto:dbermond@archlinux.org)\>" is marginal trust

:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/mujs-1.2.0-2-x86\_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).

Do you want to delete it? \[Y/n\] n

error: speech-dispatcher: signature from "Alexander Epaneshnikov <[email@alex19ep.me](mailto:email@alex19ep.me)\>" is unknown trust

:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/speech-dispatcher-0.11.1-2-x86\_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).

Do you want to delete it? \[Y/n\] n

error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)

Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

 \-> error installing repo packages
```

Version of Arch:

5.10.87-1-lts

Gnome DE

​

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `pacman -S archlinux-keyring` first, and then run `pacman -Syu`